# XSLT: Generate a new int unique ID for an element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've to update an XML using XSLT.

My previous XML element is having some element with an attribute `Id`, with an `int` value. Some element doesn't have this `Id`, as they cannot be referenced by any other element.

XML Sample:

```
<Object Id="12359" Type="TypeX">
 <Object Type="TypeA">
    <SomeOtherObject Id="112"  Type="TypeV"/>
 </Object>
 <SomeOtherOtherObject Id="1596" Type="TypeM"/>
</Object>
```

For one specific item(which I can easily manage to select with an XPATH request, I want to generate a new Id, which is not used by any other element.

Can this be done through XSLT?

I already have some key:

```
<xsl:key name="node-reference-key" match="*[@Id]" use="@Id" />
```

And I can select the element which has missing property like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@Type='TypeA']">
```

This will be run by a C# application, but I would like to avoid at all cost any c# code.

Comment: Must it be an integer? XSLT has a `generate-id()` function to assign a unique string identifier to every node.

Comment: Yes, this is a model that is currently serialized in XML, and in database, and sent to some hardware devices, there is no chance to change the type of this id

Comment: You should really tell us whether it's XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify variables in XSLT, so setting a global variable and incrementing it as you go to keep track of the next unique ID is not possible.

But you could do this:

- select the maximum ID in the document:

  ```xml
  <xsl:variable name="max-id" select="//@Id[not(. &lt; //@Id)]" />
  ```
- create a comma-delimited list of element unique IDs (with the help of `generate-id()`) and a named template:

  ```
  <xsl:variable name="missing-list">
    <xsl:call-template name="list-ids">
      <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="//*[not(@Id)]" />
    </xsl:call-tempalte>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- and -->

  <xsl:template name="list-ids">
    <xsl:param name="nodes" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(generate-id(), ',')" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  ```
- Use that list as a reference point. For any given element (that has no `@Id`), the new unique ID will be the `$max-id` plus its position in that list (you can get that with `substring-before($missing-list, generate-id())`; to get the position we count the commas:

  ```
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="
    string-length($preceding-ids)
    - string-length(translate($preceding-ids, ',', ''))
  "/>

  <xsl:attribute name="Id">
    <xsl:value-of select="$max-id + $pos + 1" />
  </xsl:attribute>
  ```

So, put together it looks like this:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="max-id" select="//@Id[not(. &lt; //@Id)]" />

    <xsl:variable name="missing-list">
      <xsl:call-template name="list-ids">
        <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="//*[not(@Id)]" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(@Id)]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

        <xsl:variable name="preceding-ids" select="
          substring-before($missing-list, generate-id())
        "/>
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="
          string-length($preceding-ids)
          - string-length(translate($preceding-ids, ',', ''))
        "/>

        <xsl:attribute name="Id">
          <xsl:value-of select="$max-id + $pos + 1" />
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="list-ids">
      <xsl:param name="nodes" />
      <xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(generate-id(), ',')" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>        
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: I see your point. I think in most case it will work. The issue I might have is that my Ids are probably not continuous but random(not my choice :/), as far I've enough Id available after the maximum used Id, it should be ok, but I'm not sure that I can count on it :(

Comment: @J4N Well, my assumption of course was that your IDs would not be confined to a maximum and an overflow was unlikely in your use case.

Comment: Ok thank you. You're right, this is very unlikely. It's just that with the Murphy's law, and since we may loss important data if this goes wrong, I'm trying to find the best way.  But the good thing is that I know there will be not a lot of items to add this Id. One question, is it possible to code in C# an XSLT tag ?

Comment: I don't understand that question. If you ask if C# can run XSLT code, yes it can.

Comment: No, more if I can do such thing: `<custom:id-generator-generate other-element-match="*/@Id" />` which would be a code in c#

Comment: In a way. You can extend .NET XSLT with your own functions, the keyword is [XSLT Extension Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf741884(v=vs.110).aspx)